# PHP : asort array by keys as strings having special chars

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a multidimensional array like this :

```
$myArray = Array
(
    "MwSt. 7%" => Array
        (
            "[rates]" => Array
                (
                    "[0]" => Array
                        (
                            "[code]" => "MwSt. 19%",
                            "[title]" => "MwSt. 19%",
                            "[percent]" => 19,
                            "[position]" => 2,
                            "[priority]" => 20,
                            "[rule_id]" => 6
                        )

                )
        ),

    "MwSt. 19%" => Array
        (
            "[rates]" => Array
                (
                    "[0]" => Array
                        (
                            "[code]" => "MwSt. 7%",
                            "[title]" => "MwSt. 7%",
                            "[percent]" => 7,
                            "[position]" => 1,
                            "[priority]" => 10,
                            "[rule_id]" => 7
                        )

                )
        )

);
```

What I want to do is to always  get "MwSt. 7%" as first Key then "MwSt. 19%"

I have function that works only when my Array begins with "MwSt. 19%", but when it begins with "MwSt. 7%" I get the wrong sorting.

```
asort($myArray, SORT_STRING);
```

Any help ?

Comment: Sounds likey you're after natural sorting, in which case you'd use `SORT_NATURAL` instead of `SORT_STRING`.

Comment: have you try `krsort()`  ?

Comment: I have tried later, it haven't worked, but now it works like a charm, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ksort($myArray);
```

is the solution ;)